# C: More Efficient Way of Checking for Equivalence in Array?

Tags: c

I have the function working, but I am looking to see if there's a more efficient way of checking if there are three of a kind in my hand of cards so I don't need so many nested loops. I'm not sure if there even is though. I am using enumerations and structures for my card in the deck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can do this. The best way depends on the type of entries you have in the array?

Are the total cards limited? What I mean is that is the maximum value that can be in the array bounded? (Since they are cards I guess they can go from 1-13).
Then the best option would be to make another array `counter` of size 13 and initialize it with 0. They iterate over all the elements and then increment the `counter` of the card you see. At any point if the counter == 3 return true else at the end false.

The implementation would be

```
int counter[13] = {0};
for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ ){
    card = hands[i].cardRank;
    counter[card]++;
    if (counter[card] == 3)
        return true;
return false;
```

If the values of the card is not bounded, you can use a hashmap in a similar way.

If hashmap datastructure is not available you, you will have to use another approach.

Here you will first sort the array. So if there are 3 occurrences they will come together. And in a single loop you can check them. For every element check if the next and the next to next element is the same as it. If yes return true.

Else finally return false.
I think the code for that would be easy to implement.

I can post if you are not able to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

You could make an integer array with one element for each card rank. This will count how many cards of that rank are in the hand. Iterate through the hand, and for each card, increment the rank-count array for the corresponding rank. Then iterate through the rank-count array and see if any values equal 3. This method would also work well for finding four of a kind. If you iterate through the rank-count array in descending order, you can find the highest rank group.

Answer (score 0):

If your hand is sorted, you can do this :

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 - 2; ++i){
  if (hand[i].cardRank == hand[i+1].cardRank && hand[i].cardRank == hand[i+2].cardRank){
    // triplets found
}
```